# Options for Archiving instead of deleting

Tags: google-app-maker

So I have been using a normal Delete Button [**widget.datasource.deleteItem();**] option to remove entries from our data models, but after a user accidentally deleted the wrong item I realized I would need to change to a recoverable method.

My first thought was to just create a Boolean or String Field titled "Archived". Then have my table hide items ([using this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44398453/trying-to-filter-only-rows-that-meet-two-criteria)) where the Archive status is set for "true" or "yes".

So Question 1 = What OnClick code would I use to tell App Maker to set the Archive Status of an item to "Yes" or "True"?

Question 2 = Is there a better method for archiving data model entries?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onClick -> "Custom Action" and use next code

```
widget.datasource.item.Archived = true;
```